# Deployment of WAR file fails in Jboss EAP 7.0.6

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

Deployment of WAR file in JBOSS EAP 7.0.6 fails with below error. However, after restarting all nodes the war file gets deployed. And the deployment works for some days without restart and error occurs again during next release deployment where it requires a restart after this error.

```
2020-06-03 22:24:14,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "app.war" (runtime-name: "app.war")
2020-06-03 22:24:15,201 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "app.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
        at java.util.zip.ZipCoder.toString(ZipCoder.java:58)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getZipEntry(ZipFile.java:583)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$900(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.next(ZipFile.java:539)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:514)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipEntryIterator.nextElement(ZipFile.java:495)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.next(JarFile.java:257)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.nextElement(JarFile.java:266)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile$JarEntryIterator.nextElement(JarFile.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.JarFileResourceLoader$1.hasNext(JarFileResourceLoader.java:265)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$2.hasNext(ModuleClassLoader.java:687)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module$4.hasNext(Module.java:773)
        at org.jboss.modules.filter.PathFilters$1.hasNext(PathFilters.java:223)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ExternalTldParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ExternalTldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
        ... 5 more


2020-06-03 22:24:15,218 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 150) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "app.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"app.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED"}}
2020-06-03 22:24:15,219 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 150) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "app.war" was rolled back with the following failure message:
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"app.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"app.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED"}}
2020-06-03 22:24:15,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment app.war (runtime-name: app.war) in 44ms
2020-06-03 22:24:15,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 150) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."app.war".POST_MODULE
```

Comment: Looks like your war is an incorrect zip file.

Comment: But I can deploy the same WAR after restarting Jboss nodes

Comment: Is this happening on Windows ? Maybe some handle on the file ?

Comment: It is in Linux. Earlier we were in JBoss EAP 6.1 and we recently migrated to EAP 7.0.6. Post migration, we face this in Jboss EAP 7.0.6